# Why there is no overloaded operator T* () in class QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, qsharedpointer

However, class `QSharedDataPointer` has it.

I always have to define a `Class::pointer` `typedef` for shortance and create a pointer with `Class::pointer(new Class)`.

Does anyone know the reasoning for this?

Comment: can you give an example sir?

Comment: You don't want to accidentally convert a shared pointer to a raw pointer and get stuck with a dangling pointer. If you want to store a pointer to an object with shared ownership, store a shared pointer (or weak pointer). If you need to pass a raw pointer to some interface, then you need to make sure the lifetime of the object is long enough. Therefore, implicit conversion from a shared pointer to a raw pointer is asking for trouble.

Comment: "I always have to..." - no you don't. `ptr.data()` does exactly what you want the operator to do, without the danger of accidentally breaking the shared semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason why T* () operator doesn't exist is because there's the [T* data() function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#data) which, like many of the other Qt classes such as QString, QByteArray etc. all provide a data() function to access the underlying data of a Qt class.

This maintains a standard interface across Qt classes.

Also, by overloading the operator, it's very easy to make a mistake if one were to change the underlying data and not realise it here. Using the data() function makes it a bit more obvious what you're doing, in my opinion.

The [data()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#data) function for QSharedPointer also warns not to delete the returned pointer, or pass it to anything which could delete it, so I see it as a function which is there if you really need it, but better if you can avoid it and if you do use it, think carefully about what is happening.

As for QSharedDataPointer, according to [the documentation,](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshareddatapointer.html#operator-T--2a) calling the operator here calls [detach()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshareddatapointer.html#detach), making it safe to call.